# Height of sub-views being auto-extended beyond the bottom of the super view by the height of the UINavigationBar in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

All of my UIViewController's show up fine inside of my UINavigationController except for one. The defective controller has a UISearchDisplayController at the top followed by a segment view and then finally a UITableView. The issue is that the height of the UITableView, which should not be more than the height of its super view, is being extended beyond the bottom of the super view by the height of the UINavigationBar. If I add a whole ton of constraints I can get it fixed however then for some reason the UISearchBar is getting moved up so that half of it is clipped by the UINavigationBar. I'm using UITableView's all over the place and this is the only UIViewController that has this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Update (photo added):
[image: UITableView extends beyond the bottom of the screen]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `edgesForExtendedLayout` set to `UIRectEdgeAll` (the default)? Maybe try adjusting this to be only `UIRectEdgeNone` or an appropriate value (this is done under View Controller > Extended Edges in Interface Builder)

Not a great answer since it's kind of hard to debug without more knowledge of the view (maybe post a screenshot of the view hierarchy and view?)

#### Update

When you mentioned that you had added a whole bunch of constraints it sounds like your constraints are fixing the problem but that you aren't adding the proper constraints to the search bar. If you are seeing the search bar pushed up to the top it is because other constraints are forcing it to be there because their priority is higher.

Take a look at your constraints and MAKE SURE you are setting top and bottom spacing constraints on the UITableView as well as the UISearchBar. This certainly seems like the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm setting UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeRight | UIRectEdgeBottom at the moment. I've updated my original post with a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `UITableView` has a constraint that pins it to the bottom of it's superview. Select the table view in your XIB, then go to:

```
Editor > Pin > Bottom Space to Superview
```

As for the other issue you've mentioned you'll need to share more about the arrangements of your views and the constraints you've applied.